# Group level authentication with FreeRadius - LDAP - FreeIPA

Tags: authentication, ldap, freeradius

I am new to radius, and LDAP and am struggling with group level authentication. I want only users in ldap group `netadmin` to be authenticated (assuming correct credentials).

In the `/etc/raddb/users` file I have added this line to the top of the file:

```
DEFAULT LDAP-Group == "cn=netadmin,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com", Auth-Type := LDAP
```

In the `/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default` file, at the bottom of the `post-auth` block, I have added:

```
# I am not sure if I need the full ldap path to the group object so I try both
if (LDAP-Group == "netadmin") {
    noop
}
elsif (LDAP-Group == "cn=netadmin,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com") {
    noop
}
else {
    reject
}
```

In the `/etc/mods-enabled/ldap` file, I have modified these lines only within these blocks (nothing else is deleted, no ordering is changed):

```
ldap {
    server = 'dc2.redacted.redacted.com'
    server = 'dc1.redacted.redacted.com'

    base_dn = 'cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com'
    user {
        base_dn = "${..base_dn}"
        filter = "(uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})"
        scope = 'sub'
    }
    group {
        base_dn = "${..base_dn}"
        filter = '(objectClass=ipausergroup)'
        membership_attribute = 'memberOf'
        scope = 'sub'
    }
}
```

With this, I run radtest locally using credentials that have worked before I made edits to attempt group authentication. In the radius debug output from the server, there are a few lines that stick out to me:

```
(0) ldap: Login attempt by "myuser"
(0) ldap: Using user DN from request "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com"
(0) ldap: Waiting for bind result...
(0) ldap: Bind successful
(0) ldap: Bind as user "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com" was successful
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (2)
Need 3 more connections to reach 10 spares
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (7), 1 of 25 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://dc2.redacted.redacted.com:389 ldap://dc1.redacted.redacted.com:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
(0)     [ldap] = ok
(0)   } # Auth-Type LDAP = ok
(0) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
(0)   post-auth {
(0)     update {
(0)       No attributes updated
(0)     } # update = noop
(0)     [exec] = noop
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)     if (LDAP-Group == "netadmin") {
(0)     Searching for user in group "netadmin"
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (3)
(0)     Using user DN from request "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com"
(0)     Checking user object's memberOf attributes
(0)       Performing unfiltered search in "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com", scope "base"
(0)       Waiting for search result...
(0)     No group membership attribute(s) found in user object
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (3)
(0)     User is not a member of "netadmin"
(0)     if (LDAP-Group == "netadmin")  -> FALSE
```

Specifically these lines:

```
(0)       Performing unfiltered search in "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com", scope "base"
(0)       Waiting for search result...
(0)     No group membership attribute(s) found in user object
```

After using ldapsearch tool, I verified that I have the `memberOf` attribute with the `netadmin` group:

```
ldapsearch -P 3 -x -W -D "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com" -b "uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com" \* +
Enter LDAP Password: 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: * + 
#

# myuser, users, accounts, redacted.redacted.com
dn: uid=myuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com
memberOf: cn=ipausers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com
...
memberOf: cn=netadmin,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com
...
uid: myuser
objectClass: ipaobject
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: ipasshuser
objectClass: inetorgperson
objectClass: organizationalperson
objectClass: krbticketpolicyaux
objectClass: krbprincipalaux
objectClass: inetuser
objectClass: posixaccount
objectClass: ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
objectClass: mepOriginEntry
```

I expected the server would see this after searching my users object, and looking for the `memberOf` attribute.

I also investigated further and captured packets with `tcpdump` and imported into wireshark to compare `radtest` and `ldapsearch`. I noticed a few differences between the sessions that stuck out to me:

1) The last `bindRequest` that `radtest` sends before `searchRequest`, uses `<ROOT>`. Using `ldapsearch`, the last `bindRequest` uses `uid=myuser,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=redacted,dc=redacted,dc=com`. BUT I the `radius` debug log says that it binds as the authenticated user, so I'm confused here.

2) When `ldapsearch` sends the `searchRequest` for attribute `memberOf` using my users `DN`, it uses a scope of `wholeSubtree`. When `radtest` sends the same request, it uses a scope of `base`. This is confusing as I set `scope = 'sub'` for both `user` and `group` blocks in my `mods-available/ldap` config.

So what am I missing that is preventing freeradius from seeing the `memberOf` attribute data to verify that my user is a part of a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I was closer than I thought. After discovering through packet capture that there was some weird binding behaviour, I looked at the debug log more closely. I realized that the binding with my username was being released:

```
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (2)
```

Also, the bind that happens for group membership checking does not use my user object DN (I believe this is an anonymous bind):

```
rlm_ldap (ldap): Opening additional connection (7), 1 of 25 pending slots used
rlm_ldap (ldap): Connecting to ldap://<redacted>:389 ldap://<redacted>:389
rlm_ldap (ldap): Waiting for bind result...
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind successful
```

This helped me fine tune my googling and I came across [some form discussion](http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2011-September/055704.html).

I asked my system admin if we had any generic accounts for this purpose and we did.

So I included at the top of the ldap block of `/etc/mods-enabled/ldap`:

```
    identity = "cn=special_ro_account,....rest_of_dn..."
    password = "xxxxxxxx"
```

And sure enough, the bind was no longer anonymous when searching for group membership and I was successfully authenticated.